# I'm traveling and need the info on my future business card

Tags: united-states, credit-card, bank-account, small-business

I'm about to open a business account, but all providers seem to provide physical credit cards for their business account. At the moment I won't be able to physically present myself at the place of business to open and use the card they send me. Is there a way to address this? A particular software or account to solve this problem?

PS: My business is fully virtual. Almost all of my business related vendors only allow a single option to pay via a business credit card.

Comment: if you can't go there, then how is it your place of business?

Answer (score 1):

There are many instances where a credit card/debit card has to be sent to a place other than the registered address. This happens when a card is lost, or it breaks, and the account owner is not at their normal residence or place of business.

With a business card there are many times where the user of the card is never located at the billing address. This frequently happens when a card needs to be mailed to an employee who lives many miles from the place of business.

The bank should be able to do this. They really need to be able to do this during the COVID crises. I know people that haven't been near their place of employment for 6 months, even though they went to the office everyday before the crisis.

Comment: Well i had apartment and before traveling i finished lease term. So far no banks seem to accept registered mail agents which differ from PO boxes. Their deal is to open accounts for current physically present people who have a physical place at the time of opening an account. This is exactly opposite of traveling.

Comment: I thought of using transferwise as my account and even asked a question here if that's a possibility. From there I should be able to make owner draws by sending money to my personal bank and recording it as such in the accounting software.